# How to migrate the UrlType from Hibernate 3.6 to 4.3 without changing database schema?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm in the process of migrating some code from Hibernate v3.4 to v4.3.10. As database I'm using H2.
When generating DDL, Hibernate 3.4 translates a `java.net.URL` field named `myUrl` into:

```
myUrl BINARY(255),
```

Now, when using Hibernate 4.3.10 the very same Java code gets "translated" into

```
myUrl VARCHAR(255),
```

Looking through documentation it seems that Hibernate 3.6 introduced a new type concept ("type registry") and specifically `java.net.URL` is not mapped to `binary`, but to `varchar`, which explains the different generated DDL above.

### Question

How do I migrate my 3.4 code to 4.3.10 while not changing the database. I.e., I'd like to be able to read the old database with Hibernate 4.3.10 annotated code.

The code in question is currently trivial:

```
@Entity
// anything to add here?
public class SomeClass {

    // what do I need to add here?
    private java.net.URL myUrl;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - this seems to work:

```
@Entity
public class SomeClass {

    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "binary(255)")
    private java.net.URL myURL;

    ...
}
```

Additional info: It's a bad idea to use properties of type `URL` as persistent properties, as during the `url.equals(otherUrl)` call the Java `URLStreamHandler` attempts to resolve the URL, i.e. a DNS lookup occurs. When you're on a slow connection, this will kill your performance, as you'll have to wait for the call to succeed or time out...